# increase the size of triangle

Tags: html, css

I have this callout cloud, please have a look at the code.

```css
div.callout {
  background-color: #444;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444, #444);
  position: relative;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
  margin: 25px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  width: 700px;
  margin-top: -58px;
  margin-left: 393px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  /*box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;*/
}

.callout::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 0.8em solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
}

.callout.right::before {
  left: -20px;
  top: 40%;
  width: -10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-right: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="callout right"> </div>
```

I want to increase the size of the triangle [image: output] (the blue one) at the start, I am unable to do that. please have a look and help me here.

Comment: it's the border-right ... and remove the negative width

Comment: Just increase the `px` value of border-right and align it. https://jsfiddle.net/j1wfqvk4/1/

Comment: ah thank you, i have been trying changing it. but didnt chage in the original code. my bad. thank you very much

Comment: `margin-top` hides half of the callout from the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase the border width and adjust the location:

```
.callout.right::before {
  left: -25px;                   /* adjust the location of triangle */
  top: 40%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-right: 10px solid blue; /* increase the border width */
}
```

Here is the code snippet:

```css
div.callout {
  background-color: #444;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444, #444);
  position: relative;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
  margin: 25px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  width: 700px;
  margin-top: -58px;
  margin-left: 393px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  /*box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;*/
}

.callout::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 0.8em solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
}

.callout.right::before {
  left: -25px;
  top: 40%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-right: 10px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="callout right"> </div>
```

Comment: negative width is not a valid value

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the code like this and you can easily change the dimension of the triangle by only changing the width of the border:

```css
div.callout {
  background-color: #444;
  background-image:linear-gradient(top, #444, #444);
  position: relative;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
  margin: 25px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.callout::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 0.8em solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
}

.callout.right::before {
  right:100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  border-right: 15px solid blue; /*Change only this value to control the size*/
}
```

```html
<div class="callout right"> </div>
```